# How DLL is loaded into memory?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, portable-executable

Just completed watching a fantastic video on CppCon [CppCon 2017: James McNellis “Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about DLLs”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPQWQfDhICA&t=1294s) This cleared my concepts about what DLLs are and what purpose they hold. But still there are few things I'm not very clear about.

At 21:34, James McNellis was saying something "Magic" but didn't actually discussed about it. He also explained what happens when we load Hello.dll not much in detail but still satisfactory. Now let's come to my Question, How DLL is loaded into memory?

Let's say I have Hello.cpp which calls `somefun()` from Hello.dll, Now when we compile and link our program, Hello.exe must have call instruction to `somefun()` which of course need a memory address. What will be this address? Will it be RVA from preferred base address of DLL? If yes then what if DLL is loaded somewhere else other than preferred address.

How DLL symbols are mapped into executable? Does Windows change every address inside executable to do this? Also what was that "magic"?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***preferred base address of DLL*** what do you mean by preferred address? I don't think DLLs can have some preference like that?

Comment: You could read up about the DLL and EXE file formats for a start to get a better understanding.

Comment: @kiner_shah - `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER::ImageBase`

Comment: @kiner_shah They have! If you watch the video, Author explains that DLL looks for preferred base address and nowadays it is done randomly. Windows legacy you know!

Comment: this is named import resolving. addresses of all `&__imp_fn` , with function name, is stored in PE. after import dll is loaded, loader is search for export function name, get it address and write to `__imp_fn`

Comment: The talk you linked to sort of talks about this at about 38:15.  The short answer is that the loader goes through all of your program's dependencies, loads the DLL into memory, finds the address of `somefun`, and initializes `__imp_somefun` to that address.

Comment: This question has to do with [`portable-executable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portable-executable) tag rather than `winapi`.

Comment: @SemihArtan Sorry my bad!